# Grails 1.3.7 utf-8 stops working after second start

Tags: grails, utf-8

I have a grails 1.3.7 application. When I remove my .grails directory and run the application, everything is fine. I can edit my domains through web interface and UTF-8 characters are saved and displayed correctly.

However when I start my application without removing .grails I get some weird characters (like these Ä?Ä?&) when I post data to a controller.

What might be the cause for it?

My data-source:

```
dbCreate = "create-drop" 
url = "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testDb"
```

Bootstrap test data is always shown correctly though.